# Unload addin .xla when uninstall Excel interop add-in

Tags: excel, interop, action, add-in, uninstallation

I have an Excel interop module A (that display on the menu bar) which in turn load another Excel add-in B.xla when Excel is loaded.

A is installed into Excel by an msi installer. B.xla is charged via

```
AddIn addin = excelApp.AddIns.Add(xlaFile);
if (!addin.Installed)
     addin.Installed = true;
```

When I uninstall A, the file B.xla that was brought by the installer is deleted. A is also deleted from the menu bar and from the list of COM add-ins. However, B is not deleted from the list of macro add-ins.

Therefore, after uninstalling A, when I open Excel the first time, a message will show saying "Add-in B is missing". I need to go to macro add-ins manager to uncheck B. Upon clicking to uncheck, Excel will say again that it cannot find B, and delete it from the list.

How can I deactivate and delete B from the list upon uninstalling A programmatically, without passing through the Add-ins dialog/manager? This is posing a problem when I perform an update of A. A is deleted from the menu bar, B.xla (the file itself) is deleted together with A, but the entry of B in Add-ins dialog is still there, and will block the update trying to register a new B into the add-ins dialog.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Addins.Add - just have A open the XLA as if it was a workbook. Then when Excel closes the XLA will close and you don't need to mess with the Addins manager.

Comment: Hello Charles, could you elaborate more how do we "just open the xla as if it was a workbook"? Would it pose a problem when I have multiple Excel instances open, and each instance open the same xla on its own ? Thanks.

Comment: Workbooks.Open("MyAddin.xla") you might want to open it read-only if you have multiple XL instances

Comment: What happens if we don't force Read_Only? Modifications from one instance change the .xla shared by all Excel instances?

Comment: No: at best it will be locked